# How to remove specific index from a list of datagridview rows

Tags: c#, list, datagridview

How to remove list of datagridview  at specific index c#

> List selectedRows = (from row in dataGridView2.Rows.Cast()
>                                                    where Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["checkBoxColumn"].Value) == true
>                                                     select row).ToList();

when this linq statement execute it will add whole row in selectedRows, i do not want to add coulmn 0 and 1 in List selectedRows  so how i will achieve this ?

Comment: is that worked for you ?

Comment: Yes but i stuck in another problem 

i want to click a button event while checking in check box

Comment: Ok, but if my answer helped you please upvote or select as accept and you need help further please update question

Comment: please guide me about this question

i want to click a button event while checking in check box –

Comment: if you want to call button event on checkbox click then , you should bind same button click event with checkbox or you can call button click event from checkbox change/click event

Comment: i am creating checkbox dynamically so how to call checkbox change/click event

Comment: its windows from ? can you please share code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to provide list of column you want to select in `select new`  as given below that will resolve issue

```
List selectedRows = (from row in dataGridView2.Rows.Cast() 
where Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["checkBoxColumn"].Value) == true 
select new {
   Field1 = row.Field<string>("Field1"),
   Field2 = row.Field<string>("Field2")
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes its a window form

i make checkbox using collection property of datagridview named as Select

i want to execute below code upon changing status of checkbox to check

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if ((bool)item.Cells[0].Value == true)
            {
                int n = dataGridView2.Rows.Add();
                dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = false;
                dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = item.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = item.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = item.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = item.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[5].Value = item.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
                dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[6].Value = item.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
                dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[7].Value = item.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
                dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[8].Value = item.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
                dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[9].Value = item.Cells[9].Value.ToString();
                dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[10].Value = item.Cells[10].Value;

                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Columns.Count; i++)
                    if (dataGridView2.Columns[i] is DataGridViewImageColumn)
                    {
                        ((DataGridViewImageColumn)dataGridView2.Columns[i]).ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Stretch;
                        break;
                    }
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView2.Rows)
                {
                    row.Cells[0].Value = true;
                }

            }
        }
```

above code is lies between button click event